# Ignore exception when using IEnumerable<FileInfo>.Count<> and skip the file/directory

Tags: c#

I am looking for the fastest way to get the number of files on a drive. So far I use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`.

```
DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesInRootDirectory = rootDirectory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

int c = 0;

foreach(FileInfo currentFile in filesInRootDirectory)
{
    //TODO: Skip if currentFile has file attribute "ReparsePoint"

    c++;
}
```

But there is an even shorter way by using the `IEnumerable<FileInfo>.Count<>` method.

```
DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesInRootDirectory = rootDirectory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

int c = filesInRootDirectory.Count<FileInfo>();
```

Unfortunately the enumeration throws a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when enumerating over a reparse point like `C:\Documents and Settings`. Is there a way to just skip those directories with the Count<> method while keeping it shorter than the first way?

PS, personally I don't care if it's one line, or four. But this is a good example to learn, if there is a general approach to that.

Answer (score -1):

It's not necessarily more performant but you could use a LINQ Statement like

```
DirectoryInfo rootDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesInRootDirectory = rootDirectory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

int c = filesInRootDirectory.Count(x => !x.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReparsePoint));
```

Update:

Tested and works taken from MSDN, but you have to be running as administrator.

```
int count = 0;
            DirectoryInfo diTop = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\");
            try
            {
                foreach (var fi in diTop.EnumerateFiles())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UnAuthTop)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}", UnAuthTop.Message);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var di in diTop.EnumerateDirectories("*"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (var fi in di.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UnAuthFile)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("UnAuthFile: {0}", UnAuthFile.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UnAuthSubDir)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("UnAuthSubDir: {0}", UnAuthSubDir.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (DirectoryNotFoundException DirNotFound)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", DirNotFound.Message);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UnAuthDir)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("UnAuthDir: {0}", UnAuthDir.Message);
            }
            catch (PathTooLongException LongPath)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", LongPath.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't what you wanted. I didn't understand the question. I'll update with a solution.

Comment: Sorry, that's not going to work. It has to find the file before it can check the flag. Finding the file is what will throw the exception. There would have to be something like `SearchOptions.IgnoreAccessExceptions` so that the `EnumerateFiles` itself will skip the files.

Comment: Just a warning that AccessExceptions are almost always caused by not running Visual Studio as an administrator.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, that is a good hint, I'll check that tomorrow.

Comment: @RaySuelzer, thanks for your effort, but I don't have trouble doing it with a foreach. The question is a different one.

Comment: @Daniel: there is no such search option. I meant that such an option would have been necessary to prevent the enumeration from throwing exceptions, and since there is no such option, the exception is expected.